# Migrating Data from HBase to FileSystem. (Writing Reducer output to Local or Hadoop filesystem)

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

My Purpose is to migrate the data from Hbase Tables to Flat (say csv formatted) files. 
I am used 
    TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(tableName, scan,
                GetCustomerAccountsMapper.class, Text.class, Result.class,
                    job);
for scanning through HBase table and TableMapper for Mapper. 
My challange is in while forcing Reducer to dump the Row values (which is normalized in flattened format) to local(or Hdfs) file system. 
My problem is neither I am able to see logs of Reducer nor I can see the any files at path that I have mentioned in Reducer.

It's my 2nd or 3rd MR job and first serious one. After trying hard for two days, I am still clueless how to achieve my goal.

Would be great if someone could show the right direction.

Here is my reducer code -

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Result> rows, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
FileSystem fs = LocalFileSystem.getLocal(new Configuration());
   Path dir = new Path("/data/HBaseDataMigration/" + tableName+"_Reducer" + "/" +        key.toString());

FSDataOutputStream fsOut = fs.create(dir,true);

for (Result row : rows) {
 try {
 String normRow = NormalizeHBaserow(
 Bytes.toString(key.getBytes()), row, tableName);
 fsOut.writeBytes(normRow);

//context.write(new Text(key.toString()), new Text(normRow));
  } catch (BadHTableResultException ex) {
    throw new IOException(ex);
}
}
fsOut.flush();          
fsOut.close();
```

My Configuration for Reducer Output

```
Path out = new Path(args[0] + "/" + tableName+"Global");
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, out);
```

Thanks in Advance - Panks

Answer (score 0):

Why not reduce into HDFS and once finished use hdfs fs to export the file

```
hadoop fs -get /user/hadoop/file localfile
```

If you do want to handle it in the reduce phase take a look at [this article on OutputFormat](http://www.infoq.com/articles/HadoopOutputFormat) on InfoQ